# Print Servers to Share Printer to AirPrint for iPads

Tags: airprint

I am trying to use the Office Edition of xPrint to create virtual printers that would allow print jobs to be routed to different paper bins on my Xerox Colorqube 8870.  It has 2 extra trays (4 total).   What I want to do is setup several virtual printers on the xPrint that do this:

1. Xerox Color: uses tray 2, prints double sided, color
2. Xerox Path: uses tray 3, prints single sided, B&W
3. Xerox Rx: uses tray 4, prints single sided, B&W

The idea is that this would allow us to print from iPads to each of these "printers" which are actually just directing output to different trays (which are each loaded with a different paper type).

I've used the manual add and socket mode to create multiple versions of the xerox with the options chosen above, but they aren't being "honored" so to speak.  Everything always comes out of tray 2.  The black and white options seem to be respected, but its disregarding the tray output selections.

I've also tried Handyprint for this, but it is even worse.  An error is created everytime a print job is sent.  Looking in the logs, its a "filter" error.

I've ensured that I have the newest drivers, i've tried using Handyprint on versions of the printer that are connected via the network as well as directly by USB, all to no avail.  I've also tried Printopia, same issue, filter error

Basically, are there other Airprint Print Servers for me to try, or is that about it?

Comment: Which "xPrint" are you talking about?

Comment: If you are still interested in an answer, I can help you. However, I'd need more specific info from you, and you'd have to run a few commands on your system and report the results. Based on these, I could give you a series of commands (or a little script) to setup your  4 print queues...